# Can I use dynamic and predictive scaling in the same cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I'm trying to create an ASG with dynamic and predictive scaling through Cloudformation. However, I'm getting the below error. Can I use dynamic and predictive scaling simultaneously within the same template?

```
Resource handler returned message: "You can't specify PredictiveScalingConfiguration for policy type: TargetTrackingScaling (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID: bd851c95-ad78-4afc-979b-f5e2e5bf188a)" (RequestToken: 387601f6-9734-ac0c-36bc-5e006f892bf2, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

```
---
Resources:
  myasg:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      MaxSize: '10'
      MinSize: '2'
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - subnet1
        - subnet2
      MixedInstancesPolicy:
        InstancesDistribution:
          OnDemandAllocationStrategy: lowest-price
          OnDemandBaseCapacity: 0
          OnDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity: 0
          SpotAllocationStrategy: lowest-price
          SpotInstancePools: 2
        LaunchTemplate:
          LaunchTemplateSpecification:
            LaunchTemplateName: mylaunchtemplate
            Version: 1
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: Production
          PropagateAtLaunch: true
        - Key: Purpose
          Value: WebServerGroup
          PropagateAtLaunch: false
  scalingpolicy:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: myasg
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      TargetTrackingConfiguration:
        DisableScaleIn: false
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 30
      PredictiveScalingConfiguration:
        MaxCapacityBreachBehavior: IncreaseMaxCapacity
        MaxCapacityBuffer: 0
        MetricSpecifications:
          - TargetValue: 30
        Mode: ForecastAndScale
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-predictive-scaling.html) indicates that it is a best practice to "Use predictive scaling with dynamic scaling."

So, yes it should be possible. The way to do this in CloudFormation is to associate multiple scaling policies with a single AutoScalingGroup.

For example (untested):

```
  scalingpolicy1:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: myasg
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      TargetTrackingConfiguration:
        DisableScaleIn: false
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ASGAverageCPUUtilization
        TargetValue: 30

  scalingpolicy2:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName:
        Ref: myasg
      PolicyType: PredictiveScaling
      PredictiveScalingConfiguration:
        MaxCapacityBreachBehavior: IncreaseMaxCapacity
        MaxCapacityBuffer: 0
        MetricSpecifications:
          - TargetValue: 30
        Mode: ForecastAndScale
```